# publish rdlc files in .net web app?

Tags: .net, report, rdlc

We have a web site that uses rdlc files to show some reports, but when I publish the website within visual studio these files are not included.

how do I add these files to the publication?

is copying these rdlc files to the publication secure?

thanks

Answer (score 26, accepted):

When I included my .rdlc files they would not output during a publish as well.

To solve this click on the file and look in the properties window.

Under 'Build Action' my project had the setting of 'Embedded Resource'.
Changing this setting to 'Content' fixed this issue for me.

Comment: this is the correct solution. Eton's answer implies that you have to manually copy them every time you publish; changing the Build Action does this for you

Answer (score 2):

1. Go to the properties of the rdlc file
2. Set BuildAction - 'Content'
3. Set Copy to Output Directory - Do not copy

Answer (score -2):

I had the same thing happen to me, it was too strange since SOME of them were published and some weren't, even though they are part of the same project.

My solution was to simply copy the rdlc files over to the published folder and it works as expected.